# Remove a charactrer string from character vector in R

Tags: r

I want to remove a character string from a character vector in R

Example input:

```
  [1] "Species1"      "Species2"    
  [3] "Species3"      "Species4"    
  [5] "Species5"      "Species6"     
  ...
```

Desired output (e.g. remove Species2 and preserve order):

```
  [1] "Species1"      "Species3"    
  [3] "Species4"      "Species5"    
  [5] "Species6"      "Species7"
```

Comment: Just do `v1[v1 != "Species2"]` ?

Comment: `setdiff(s, "Species2")`